# Field extension of finite fields are always separable?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

I guess the answer is very trivial, but at the moment I don't get it.
Let $p$ prime. Consider the extension $\mathbb{F}_{p^n} | \mathbb{F}_p$ with $n \in \mathbb{N}$ arbitrary.
We know that this is a galois extension.
But why this extension is separable?
Especially for $p|n$ it can't be separable, because there is at least one element who's derivative of his minimal polynomial is zero?

Where is the misstake? Ty for help.

Comment: To answer your question about $\mathbb{F}_{q^n}$ over $\mathbb{F}_q$, where $q$ is a prime power, you can just show that the polynomial $x^{q^n}-x$ has no repeated root in the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{F}_q$ and the roots of $x^{q^n}-x$ are precisely the elements of $\mathbb{F}_{q^n}$.

Comment: But this extension is algebraic since it's normal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there are no elements $\alpha\in\Bbb{F}_{p^n}$ such that the minimal polynomial $m(x)$ of $\alpha$ would have zero derivative. For $m'(x)$ to be zero, we must have the form
$$
m(x)=\sum_{i}a_ix^{pi}
$$
for some finite set of coefficients $a_i\in\Bbb{F}_p$. By Little Fermat $a_i^p=a_i$ for all $i$, so in fact
$$
m(x)=\left(\sum_ia_ix^i\right)^p.
$$
But this contradicts the fact that a minimal polynomial is irreducible.

Comment: The key implication is: $$m'(x)=0\implies \text{$m(x)$ is not irreducible.}$$ This fails for some transcendental extensions of $\Bbb{F}_p$ but holds for all the finite fields $K$, because we then have $K^p=K$. Look up *perfect fields*.